# Configurable product price is not change

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have one configurable product and many associated products.In the product page,i changed the options but product price is not change. Iam using **magento1.9**

Can anyone please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check, If the options have price in configurable product.
please refer following screenshot
[image: price]